# Reading the Heroku dyno formation with the CLI

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, dyno, hirefire

We are using HireFire to manage multiple DelayedJob queues, with queues associated with different `Procfile` entries that might vary by application.

For 95% of the day some of the dyno types in the formation are scaled to 0. (Basically, overnight batch jobs start, submit to one queue or other, and Performance-M or L dynos are scaled to 1, 2, or 3 to handle the jobs, then they scale back to zero when the queues are empty).

The CLI `ps` command will retrieve information on the running processes, but if one or more of the dyno types is scaled to zero, they do not appear.

Does anyone know of a way of retrieving dyno formation info even when the dynos are not running?

Comment: What information is it you are searching for that is not in the `Procfile`?

Comment: @DenisCornehl It would certainly be the info in the Procfile, so I could `heroku run cat Procfile -a my-app`, but that requires running a process on the app. I was wondering if the CLI had a way of returning this info instead.